# How to use go list -u -m all with vendoring mode?

Tags: go, go-modules

I just upgraded to go1.14 and running `go list -u -m all` command with -mod=vendor GOFLAG , i encountered **can't determine available upgrades using the vendor directory**. I went through the release notes (https://golang.org/doc/go1.14#go-command) but couldn't figure out why this error. ( My go.mod and vendor/modules.txt were in sync ).

When to use `-mod=readonly` like `go list -mod=readonly -u -m all` command? What's wrong with using  `go list -u -m all` with `-mod=vendor`?

Any pointers would be much appreciated . Thank you.

```
GOGOPATH=/home/vagrant/go_workspace
GO111MODULE=on
GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor
============================================
go list  -u -m all
go list -m: can't determine available upgrades using the vendor directory
        (Use -mod=mod or -mod=readonly to bypass.)
```

Comment: Without -mod=readonly the go tool might modify go.{mod,sum} which you do not want so use it.

Comment: without -mod=readonly i get `can't determine available upgrades using the vendor directory` error , any pointer why this error ?

Answer (score 5):

`-mod=vendor` requests that the `go` command resolve information about your dependencies using *only* the information in the `vendor` directory.

The `vendor` directory necessarily does not contain information about available upgrades, because the `vendor` directory itself is created at a single point in time. In order to determine available upgrades, you must make a network connection to either a module proxy server or the origin server to see what other versions have become available.

So the two flags really are incompatible: either you can check for upgrades, or you can use only what's in the `vendor` directory, but not both at once.